# getElementByClassName with multiple results

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a small code created with DOM and Javascript. It should create a tooltip below a link. It works as intended for one link but now I just realized that I do need to have multiple links, so I can't use `<a id>` like I have used for now.

In my code I have currently commented out xmlhttp part but I do need it in the future. Don't mind about it.

Javascript:

```
   function createTooltip(str)
   {
      if (str == "" || !str)
      {
         return;
      }

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
         xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else // for IE5 and IE6
      {
         xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

      /*xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
         {*/
            //document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            var tooltip = document.createElement("div");
            var link = document.getElementById("tooltip");
            tooltip.setAttribute('id', 'tooltip-style');
            tooltip.innerHTML = "<p>piece of crap</p>";

            if (str == link.rel)
            {
               link.parentNode.insertBefore(tooltip, link.nextSibling);
            }
         /*}
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "tooltip.php?s="+str, true);
      xmlhttp.send();*/
   }

   function removeTooltip(str)
   {
      var tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip-style");
      tooltip.setAttribute('id', '');
      tooltip.innerHTML = "";
   }
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" rel="35" onmouseover="createTooltip(this.rel);" onmouseout="removeTooltip(this.rel);" id="tooltip">Item</a><br><br>
<a href="#" rel="25" onmouseover="createTooltip(this.rel);" onmouseout="removeTooltip(this.rel);" id="tooltip">Item</a>
```

The code is supposed to create a div block below the link you hovered, not on every link. I tried playing around with getElementByClassName for multiple hours but I just can't get it to work. Also going to note that the `<a rel>` value is not most likely going to be a unique value in the future.

Thank you for your time. I do appreciate it.

Comment: *"I tried playing around with getElementByClassName for multiple hours but I just can't get it to work"* That may be because it's `getElementsByClassName` (note the plural).

Comment: getElementsByClassName will return you an array of elements containing the class, so you need to select the desired class properly. like getElementsByClassName('class-name')[index_of_class]

Comment: Separately: What class were you looking for? There is no `class="..."` in your quoted markup. The "class" in `getElementsByClassName` refers to a class in the `class` attribute (the same one used by CSS when you use a selector like `.some-class`).

Comment: T.J Crowder, I did try with plural, I just mistyped it in the post.
Ichigo Kurosaki, yes I do know it returns an array. I tried looping it with multipely way without it working.
T.J Crowder, I changed them back to IDs after classes did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a = getElementsByClassName('classname');
for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
     //each element will be a[i] do whatever with them you want
}
```

Comment: For some reason this worked. But I tried with this way, exactly same, but dunno why it didn't work out then. Well, the main thing is that this works. Thank you Ashkan.

Comment: things like this happens a lot in programming and when you get a problem with what you have done a lot and very simple it just makes a programmer maddd. :)  happy programming